# Android Remote Notification ReCreates Activity (Xamarin C#)

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, remote-notifications

I am using Firebase to generate a remote notification for my App.

My Activity chain is as follows

Splash Activity (Launchmode SingleTask, NoHistory = True)

calls

Login Activity (Launchmode Standard (default), NoHistory = True)

calls

Main Activity (Launchmode SingleTask, NoHistory = False)

If I place my App in the background (main activity has Paused) and rerun it from the desktop, the Resume event fires in the main activity and all is well.

However if I place the App in the background (main activity has Paused) and select a notification for the App from the Notification List on the desktop, the Splash Activity Create method fires.

How can I make the behaviour for Notification triggering be the same as for resuming from background.  I dont want the user to login every time they click on a notification.

Thanks

Comment: I have found that setting NoHistory=False in the Main Activity gives me the behaviour I was looking for, i.e. Create does not now fire, but it resumes.  However. since I am trying to handle a notification, I am trying to pass the Intent data from the Splash Activity through to the Main Activity.  This works if the Activity is Created, but now I have worked around that to just Resume the existing Activity, the intent with the notification data is no longer passed.   The question now becomes; how do I pass an intent to an Activity which is being resumed rather than created ?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I pass an intent to an Activity which is being resumed rather than created ?

You should implement [OnNewIntent(Intent intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) in your `MainActivity`. You can then use that to set the 'current' Intent to be the new Intent.

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    if (intent != null)
        Intent = intent;
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Then in `OnResume()` you can use the intent to restore your notification data.

```
Intent intent = Intent;
```